# Woocommerce Add to Cart redirect external url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Am I doing something wrong using the below code to have the function of Redirection to an external / third party URL when Add to Cart on WooCommerce site?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $redirect_url) {
    $redirect_url = "https://IWANTTOREDIRECTHERE.COM";
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

I would like the redirect to external url for ALL products globally across the site but, not sure how I can go about doing this.

Comment: Can it be because of the `priority` of `add_filter()` (3rd parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

This script targets the add-to-cart button on a single product page. Adjust the selector if your setup is different. When the button is clicked, it prevents the default action (adding to the cart) and redirects the user to the specified URL.

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Find the add-to-cart button
    var addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.single_add_to_cart_button');

    // Check if the button exists
    if (addToCartButton) {
        // Add a click event listener to the button
        addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // Prevent the default action of the button (adding to the cart)
            event.preventDefault();

            // Perform your custom redirection
            window.location.href = 'https://example.com'; // Replace with your desired URL
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: But I still require the functionality of the cart. I will be using the Woo REST API on an external site to getcart so, the redirect must happen after a successful add to cart

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by applying the following steps:

Firstly, for external urls, we must whitelist the domain using the "allowed_redirect_hosts" hook:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'mycustom_extend_allowed_domains_list' );
function mycustom_extend_allowed_domains_list( $hosts ){
    
    $hosts[] = 'wordpress.com';
    $hosts[] = 'externaldomainhere.com';
    
    return $hosts;
    
}
```

Then, we must use the woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect hook like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 1 );
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $redirect_url) {
    $redirect_url = 'https://externaldomainhere.com';
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;
}
```

This works for the Add to Cart button on Category Page and Single Product Page. Tested and works... Hope it helps anyone else looking to do the same!